# Sync current progress bar with overall when read a files

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, filestream

So, i try to synchronize two progress bar like that:

```
long TotalSize; //Total size of files in Directory "Source"

foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles("Source", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    long FileSize; //Current file size in recursive search 
    long CurrentFileSize //It's mean `+=` add size of current file in recursive search
    
    using (FileStream readfile = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];
        int Readbyte;
        long TotalByteSize = 0;
        
        while ((readbyte = readfile.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            TotalByteSize += Readbyte;
            CurrentFileProgress.Value = (int)((float)TotalByteSize / FileSize * 100.0f); //Progress when reading current file bytes
        }
    }
    OverallFilesProgress.Value = (int)((float)CurrentFileSize/ TotalSize * 100.0f); //Overall progress when read all files 
}
```

This works fine, but it's not a synchronization, it - paralleled the progress bar. Can u show me example how to really synchronize two progress bar (current and overall). In my head, I understand that I need to somehow save the read bytes of the current file into a variable, and then add this to the overall progress, but in practice I can’t do it. Second problem is - overall progress bar is start later 1 sec (bcuz wait while loop). P.S. Only filestream, no BGW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have some issues with your counters, it should probably look something like:

```
int overallTotal = ...; 
int overallCompleted = 0;
foreach(var file in files){
    // open file etc
    int currentCompleted = 0;
    int currentTotal = file.Size;
    while (...){
        overallCompleted += noReadBytes;
        currentCompleted += noReadBytes;
        CurrentFileProgress.Value = (int)(currentCompleted * 100.0f/ currentTotal );
        OverallFilesProgress.Value = (int)(overallCompleted * 100.0f/ overallTotal );
    }
}
```

That should ensure both progress bars are updated continuously. Note that you should probably do the reading on a background thread and use [`Progress<T>.Report`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1.system-iprogress-t--report?view=net-7.0#system-progress-1-system-iprogress((t))-report(-0)) to report progress. Or use asynchronous reads to avoid blocking the UI thread.

Comment: Perfect! Why didn't I think of this before? Easy, but how? `overallCompleted` and  `currentCompleted` - is equivalent. Why can't we just use only `currentCompleted`. I try like this before, but wo duplicate. You just put the `overallCompleted` out of the `foreach loop` and it worked!

Comment: @Malcom, `overallCompleted` and `currentCompleted` are **not** equivalent. the first contains the number of copied bytes for *all* the files, and the second the number of bytes copied for the *current* file.

Comment: You are right, sorry for my inattention. Adrenaline rush, after two days of trying to fix it!

Answer (score 1):

One of many ways is with a for-next loop on the count of the `Directory.GetAllFiles()` result and then use the `FileStream.ReadAsync()` method to read (for example) 1 MB chunks without blocking the UI. The ProgressBar updates will be on the UI thread in this way, as they should be.

[image: screenshot]

```
const int ONE_MB = 0x100000;
private async Task loadFilesAsync(string selectedPath)
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(selectedPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    for (int count = 0; count < files.Length; count++)
    {
        progressBarOverall.Value = (int)((count/(float)files.Length) * 100);
        string path = files[count];

        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
        {
            int offset = 0;
            long length = fileStream.Length;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
            int readLength = ONE_MB;
            while (offset != length)
            {
                if (offset + readLength > length)
                {
                    readLength = (int)length - offset;
                }
                offset += await fileStream.ReadAsync(buffer, offset, readLength);
                progressBarSingle.Value = (int)((offset / (float)length) * 100);
            }
        }
    }
    tableLayoutPanelStatus.Visible = false;
}
```

---

**Testing**

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tsmiBrowseFolder.Click += onClickBrowseFolder;
    }

    private readonly FolderBrowserDialog _folderBrowser = new FolderBrowserDialog
    {
        RootFolder= Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData,
    };
    private void onClickBrowseFolder(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(_folderBrowser.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
        {
            _ = loadFilesAsync(_folderBrowser.SelectedPath);
        }
    }
    .
    .
    .        
}
```

Comment: That's is too Great work Sir. It's a the StackOverflow cannot make it so that there are 2 correct answers at once! But i'm upvoted for u'r answer too! Tnk u so much!